# C++ placement new, inheritance and destructor

Tags: c++, placement-new

Fellows,

When using placement-new on a class hierarchy, the base class must do the de-allocation. Otherwise, the base class destructor will be called on a de-allocated object.
I want to be able to perform the de-allocation from a derived class. So I am open for ideas and suggestions! (NB: I am not married to placement-new, but I want to have custom memory management instead of new/delete).

Please find below a sample piece of code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <new>

class CParent
{
public :
    CParent() {
        printf("CParent()\n");
    }

    virtual ~CParent() {
        printf("~CParent()\n");
    }
};

class CAllocator
{
private :
    void Free(uint8_t *buffer) {
        printf("CAllocator::Free(%p)\n", buffer);
        delete [] buffer;
    }

    class CChild : public CParent
    {
    public :
        CChild(CAllocator &allocator, uint8_t *buffer)
            : mAllocator(allocator), mBuffer(buffer)
        {
            printf("CChild()\n");
        }

        ~CChild() {
            printf("~CChild()\n");
            mAllocator.Free(mBuffer);
        }

    private :
        CAllocator &mAllocator;
        uint8_t *mBuffer;
    };

public :
    CParent *Alloc() {
        uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[sizeof(CChild)];
        printf("CAllocator::Alloc() = %p\n", buffer);
        return new (buffer) CChild(*this, buffer);
    }
};

int main()
{
    CAllocator allocator;
    CParent *object = allocator.Alloc();

    // NB: Can't do `delete object` here because of placement-new
    object->~CParent();
    return 0;
}
```

Which gives the following output:

```
CAllocator::Alloc() = 0x2001010
CParent()
CChild()
~CChild()
CAllocator::Free(0x2001010)
~CParent()
```

So `~CParent()` is called after the memory is freed...
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Well, don't call `mAllocator.Free(mBuffer);` from within the destructor. You're not allocating that memory from within the constructor, are you? Then you should do the same for deallocation, call it after the destructor call completes.

Comment: This might help: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing the following notions in such a way that it makes me think that you are unclear on what they are supposed to be:

1. Base classs/derived class destructors.
2. Placement `new` operator.
3. Memory allocation and deallcation.

When you use the plain old `operator new` to allocate objects, two things happen:

1. Memory is allocated for the object.
2. The constructor of the object (for classes that have constructors) is called.

When you call `operator delete` on pointers that were returned by `operator new`, two things happen:

1. The destructor of the object is called.
2. Memory is deallocated.

When you use a placement `new` operator, you have to:

1. Allocate memory before the call to the placement `new` operator.
2. Use the pre-allocated memory in the call to `new`. A constructor of the class is called to initialize the object.

For such objects, you have to:

1. Call the destructor explicitly.
2. Deallocate the memory using a method that matches with the way the memory was allocated. If you used `operator new char[size];` to allocate memory, use `delete [] ptr;` to deallocate the memory. If you used `malloc(size)` to allocate memory, use `free(ptr)` to deallocate the memory.

To keep your code clean, you should separate:

1. The responsibility for allocation and deallocation of memory.
2. The responsibility for calling constructors and destructors.

In your posted code, the class `CChild` seems to be unclean. It's not clear whether it is meant to be a user facing class or a helper class to help you manage memory.

If you meant it to be a user facing class, I would refactor the code to:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <new>

class CParent
{
   public :
      CParent() {
         printf("CParent()\n");
      }

      virtual ~CParent() {
         printf("~CParent()\n");
      }
};

class CChild : public CParent
{
   public :
      CChild()
      {
         printf("CChild()\n");
      }

      ~CChild() {
         printf("~CChild()\n");
      }

   private :
};

class CAllocator
{
   public :
      void Free(uint8_t *buffer) {
         printf("CAllocator::Free(%p)\n", buffer);
         delete [] buffer;
      }


      uint8_t *Alloc(size_t size) {
         uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[size];
         printf("CAllocator::Alloc() = %p\n", buffer);
         return buffer;
      }
};

int main()
{
   CAllocator allocator;
   uint8_t *buffer = allocator.Alloc(sizeof(CChild));

   CParent* object = new (buffer) CChild;

   object->~CParent();

   allocator.Free(buffer);

   return 0;
}
```

If you meant `CChild` to be used as a helper class for managing memory, the first thing you'll have to do is make sure that `CAllocator::Alloc()` and `CAlloctor::Free()` are symmetric. Since `Alloc()` returns a pointer to a `CParent`, you'll need to change `Free()` to accept a pointer to a `CParent` and does the right thing with it. Here's what I think the code should look like:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <new>

class CParent
{
   public :
      CParent() {
         printf("CParent()\n");
      }

      virtual ~CParent() {
         printf("~CParent()\n");
      }
};

class CAllocator
{
   private :

      class CChild : public CParent
      {
         public :
            CChild(uint8_t *buffer) : mBuffer(buffer)
            {
               printf("CChild()\n");
            }

            ~CChild() {
               printf("~CChild()\n");

               // The object has ownership of the buffer.
               // It can deallocate it.
               delete [] mBuffer;
            }

         private :
            uint8_t *mBuffer;
      };

   public :

      // Make Alloc and Free symmetric.
      // If Alloc() returns a CParent*, make sure Free()
      // accepts the same value and does the right thing
      // with it.

      CParent *Alloc() {
         uint8_t *buffer = new uint8_t[sizeof(CChild)];
         printf("CAllocator::Alloc() = %p\n", buffer);

         // Transfer the ownership of buffer to CChild
         return new (buffer) CChild(buffer);
      }

      void Free(CParent* object) {
         printf("CAllocator::Free(%p)\n", object);
         object->~CParent();
      }


};

int main()
{
   CAllocator allocator;

   CParent *object = allocator.Alloc();
   allocator.Free(object);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sahu. Thank you for your input. In your second example, `~CParent()` will still be called after the memory is deallocated. I think however that the lack of symetry in my first example complicates things. If the memory is allocated in `CAllocator`, it should also be freed in `CAllocator`. I think your 2nd example could be slightly modified to make it work: the memory can be freed in `CAllocator::Free()` after the call to `object->~CParent()` instead of in `~CChild()`. I'll give it a try.

Comment: `object->~CParent()` will call `~CChild()`, which will call `~CParent()` first before executing the lines in the body of `~CChild()`. Hence, `~CParent()` will be called **before** memory is deallocated, **not after**.

Comment: @Sahu: Did you try it? I tried and the body of `~CChild()` definitely gets executed before `~CParent()`. This is, I believe, how C++ is meant to work. I also tried the slightly modified version of your 2nd example, and it does work perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @seeker6, you are right. I was confused for a moment.